how to fix mmenu.js 9.3 accessible validation error
When using mmenu.js, I get a wcag 2.1. validation error.
"Accessible name does not match or contain the visible label text"
Further infos: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Techniques/failures/F96.html
for example in this part of code:
<a aria-label="Close submenu" href="#mm-2" class="mm-btn mm-btn--prev mm-navbar__btn">About</a>

Is there a way to fix the error?
Shouldn't the generated code look like this?
<a aria-label="About" href="#mm-2" class="mm-btn mm-btn--prev mm-navbar__btn">About</a>


Hi Andy. I’m afraid this question still needs some work. The error message for the first code snippet is correct. “About” is not included in “Close submenu”. But you are asking another question, that of the generated code. We can’t answer that question, if you don’t share the code you use to create the item, and the parameters you pass to it.
